# Ограничение при скачивании

Tags: java, spring

Когда качаю файл размером 4.7гигабайт через данный код, показывает что файл 384мб и качает только эти 384мб, не могу понять из-за чего это ограничение?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/files/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void  getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String url = (String) request.getAttribute(
            HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "application.properties";
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        properties.load(is);
        try {
            properties.load(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("ОШИБКА: Файл свойств отсуствует!");
        }
        Path file = Paths.get(properties.getProperty("dir")).resolve(url);
        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
        File downloadFile = new File(file.toString());
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
        // get MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(file.toString());
        if (mimeType == null) {
            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        // set content attributes for the response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
        // set headers for the response
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
                downloadFile.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        // get output stream of the response
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
        try {
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outStream.close();
        is.close();
    }
```

Comment: Намёк: `response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());`

Comment: А так да качает, спс, изменил на setContentLengthLong

Comment: @Roman, почему бы вам не оформить свой комментарий как ответ, чтобы автор закрыл вопрос?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Размер 4.7 гигабайта, если перевести в байты, не влезает в тип `int`, поэтому в строчке

```
response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
```

у вас происходит переполнение. Чтобы этого не происходило, либо используйте метод [`setContentLengthLong(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLengthLong-long-) из Servlet 3.1:

```
response.setContentLengthLong(downloadFile.length());
```

либо передавайте размер в виде `String`:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(downloadFile.length()));
```